# python - tensor : access a value

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Given below is the output of VGG16 model. The command `VGG16.classifier[6]` output shows `Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)` I'm not able to understand how this works. ALso,how can I print the values of linear

```
    VGG(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace)
    (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (6): ReLU(inplace)
    (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): ReLU(inplace)
    (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace)
    (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (13): ReLU(inplace)
    (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): ReLU(inplace)
    (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (18): ReLU(inplace)
    (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (20): ReLU(inplace)
    (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (22): ReLU(inplace)
    (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (25): ReLU(inplace)
    (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (27): ReLU(inplace)
    (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (29): ReLU(inplace)
    (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VGG16](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/models.html#torchvision.models.vgg16) model is divided into two groups of layers named `features` and `classifier`. You can access them as `VGG16.features` and `VGG16.classifier`:

```
>>> VGG16 = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
>>> VGG16.classifier
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
  (1): ReLU(inplace)
  (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
  (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
  (4): ReLU(inplace)
  (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
  (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
)
```

Further, you can access each layer of these groups of layers using indices. For example, to access the first layer of `classifier` portion of model, you can do:

```
>>> VGG16.classifier[0]  # first layer of classifier portion
Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
# and so on...
>>> VGG16.classifier[3]  # fourth layer of classifier portion
Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
```